# How to show more posts on an archive page?

Tags: custom-post-types, actions, archives, pre-get-posts

I'd like to show more posts on my custom archive page, but can't seem to figure out the right way to do it. Currently it displays 10, which is the number set in WP Settings and the number I'd like on my homepage. But on archives I'd like more.

Right now the call for posts is super simple:

```
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <?php
                // Start the loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

This works nicely and works with my pagination. Is there a way to modify that to 100 posts? Is this where `pre_get_posts` would work? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pre_get_posts` action to achieve that:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ($query) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 100 );
    }
});
```

In the code above I use `is_archive()`, but you can use other [conditional tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) in there...

Comment: Excellent. And where is this correctly placed? After have_posts(), after the while statement, or at the end of the entire section where I'd normally add an action? Thank you!

Comment: Oh, should it be in the functions.php? That makes more sense. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you should place it in functions.php of your active theme.

Comment: thank you for the code. I used it to display 9 posts per page. But even if the number of posts is displayed correctly, pagination disappeard (for categories with more than 9 posts).
I'd like to display 9 posts and leave pagination in place at the bottom of the archive page.
How can I archieve that?
Thanks!

Comment: @AlessandraDelPuglia don't post comments as solutions to the question. Having only 1 reputation is not an excuse and the system will flag you as a spambot if you continue. If you have a new question, [you should ask a new question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), you can always link here for context